# To find if a item's price has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is probably easy to do but I have a table which list items by price and has a version number for each item, so there is duplicate items with the same itemID and item name but the different versions might have different prices. I wanted a simple sql statement to check which items prices have changed

```
itemid | item | price  |version | date
1         a      1.13    1        2011-12-01
2         b      5.13    1        2011-12-01
3         c      3.66    1        2011-12-01
4         a      1.03    2        2012-01-09
5         b      5.13    2        2012-01-09
6         c      3.33    2        2012-01-09
```

There will be numerous versions so guess I need to some kind of comparison function but not sure where to start in SQL.

So the above example I would only want to fetch back item `a` and `c` as there price has changed from the previous version.

Comment: changed compared to what?  a later point in time?  a max_version stored somewhere else?

Comment: Changed from the previous versions

Comment: changed from previous versions stored in another table by item?  You need a comparison source.

Comment: Kind of silly to version ineffective price changes, IMHO...

Comment: if you had a date column, you could see which prices changed as of any given point in time...

Comment: Its not my data, I'm just trying to query it... If there are say 200,000 records which I've downloaded and only 2000 have changed I just wanted to know about these 2000 items. There is a date field as well

Comment: @Paul Is it safe to say that you're trying to find the *effective* or *most recent* price for each item?

Comment: No thats easy to do, I want to find if the price has changed from the previous version

Comment: From the previous version you downloaded?  Then you need to store the item key and version from your previous download to compare with the items and versions from your current download.

Comment: @Paul Then I don't see how the query I posted doesn't solve this for you.

Comment: Thats what I have done in effect? All items which are version 1 and have that date are from one download. The next download has version 2 and a new date

Comment: @Yuck because it doesn't find which items have changed price, just because you group by price and item

Comment: @Paul Umm, yes it does. If you group by **both** `price` and `item` and then limit the result set to those with **more than one** group, you get only those items with changed prices.

Comment: so you want all the items in the previous download table which have a later version in the current download table?

Comment: I just want a list of items which price has changed from the previous version

Comment: @Paul I updated my answer to show each step in the process of doing what you are looking for. Please **run** the samples provided before dismissing them as invalid.

Comment: @Yuck ok thanks for that I'll check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(DISTINCT price) prices
FROM yourTable
/* WHERE clause would go here */
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT price) > 1
```

Optionally include:

```
WHERE version in (1,2)
```

- if you only want to compare the specific versions 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a list of items where the prices has changed from the previous version:

```
WITH V AS (
  SELECT MAX(version) CurrentFileVersion
  FROM yourTable
), C AS (
  SELECT item, price, version
  FROM yourTable INNER JOIN V ON yourTable.version = V.CurrentFileVersion
), P AS (
  SELECT item, price, version
  FROM yourTable INNER JOIN V ON yourTable.version = (V.CurrentFileVersion - 1)
)
SELECT C.item
FROM C INNER JOIN
     P ON C.item = P.item
WHERE C.price <> P.price;
```

This even shows all the intermediate steps. I honestly can't make it any more simple or explicit to follow than this.

Comment: They will all have more than one version though, I just want the ones which price has changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM Prices T
where exists (
SELECT 1 from Prices
    where item = T.item and version = T.version - 1 and price != T.price
)
```

Ps. change "Prices" with your table name

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want this information to update your table with data from this table.

I would pull the most current version of each record inot a temp table or CTE. THen I would run a MERGE statement to insert any new records or update any where the price is different from the existing price.